# While using the DataError event how does one get e.Context to be parsed?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I currently have a datagridview that a user uses to enter data.  In order to catch bad formatting i searched and read that the event `DataError` was the way to go.  The few samples i do find all seem to think that the `e.Context` has a single `DataGridViewDataErrorContext` like so.

```
if (e.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)    
{    
    MessageBox.Show("Commit error");    
}
```

But when i try to implement the same thing on a test grid i get the following for my `e.Context` instead.  It has a list like so: `Parsing | Commit | CurrentCellChange`

[Screenshot of e.Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAIJw.png)

Notice that the value for `e.Context` is a list of values and not a single one like the sample code online show it to be.  Am i doing something incorrectly or missing a step? How does one have that seperated?

I'm using VS 2010 Prof.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b828eb41-4199-4b83-8334-26f4c1330214/datagridview-dataerror-event-handler

Comment: @RameshRajendran that link refers to VB and thats similiar code to what i found for C# but doesn't clear up why `e.Context` is a list for me.

Comment: Using the following source code found [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewdataerroreventargs.context.aspx) @ MSDN

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it was the correct path to take but I ended up modifying it slightly to get it to work.

```
    //if (e.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    if (e.Context.ToString().Contains(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit.ToString()))
    {

              MessageBox.Show("Commit error");
    }

    //if (e.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange)
    if (e.Context.ToString().Contains(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange.ToString()))
    {

              MessageBox.Show("Cell change");
    }

    //if (e.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Parsing)
    if (e.Context.ToString().Contains(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Parsing.ToString()))
    {

              MessageBox.Show("Parsing error");
    }

    //if (e.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.LeaveControl)
    if (e.Context.ToString().Contains(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.LeaveControl.ToString()))
    {

              MessageBox.Show("Leave control error");
    }
```

This allows me to check what is in `e.Context`

Answer (score 0):

As of .NET Framework 4, I think the preferred way is to use the [Enum.HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.
This, of course, should be used with Enum types that are marked with the [Flags] attribute ([DataGridViewDataErrorContexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewdataerrorcontexts%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is one of them).

I just recently wrote this little helper method, which you may find helpful:

```
private string ReadableDataGridViewContext(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
{
    var translations = new Dictionary<DataGridViewDataErrorContexts, string> {
        { DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.ClipboardContent, "Copying Data to the Clipboard" },
        { DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit, "Committing Data" },
        { DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange, "Moving Focus to a different Cell, due to error in the Cell being left" },
        { DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Display, "Displaying Data in a Cell" },
        { DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Formatting, "Formatting Data" },
        { DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.InitialValueRestoration, "Restoring Cell Data" },
        { DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.LeaveControl, "Leaving the Grid" },
        { DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Parsing, "Parsing Data" },
        { DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.PreferredSize, "Calculating the preferred size for a Cell" },
        { DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.RowDeletion, "Deleting a Row" },
        { DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Scroll, "Scrolling over the Grid" }
    };

    var list = (from contextFlag in translations.Keys
                    where context.HasFlag(contextFlag)
                    select translations[contextFlag]).ToList();
    return String.Join(",", list);
}
```